# Can I use JButton as a parameter for a constructor

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jbutton

So I have two classes, one is a GUI class with my JButtons, JFrames etc.... My other class has my main method along with a static method to play a sound. I am trying to create a constructor that will allow me to easily create a bunch of quiz questions, it will play a sound, ask the user to identify what makes that noise, and then display if the answer was correct or incorrect.  I'm trying to put the JButton in the constructor as the  "correct response" for the question that will be created, but I am getting a cannot find symbol error

This is my first Class

```
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class NateApp {

    private static JLabel label = new JLabel("Select the correct answer");





    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       File shred = new File("shredNoise.WAV");
       // PlaySound(noise);
        generateQuestion(" Shred", " Airplane ", "Car", "Pool Party", buttonA, shred);
    }

    public static void PlaySound(File Sound)
    {
        try{
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
            clip.start();


            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
    public static void generateQuestion(String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4, JButton correctAnswer, File audioQue)
    {
        new GUI(option1, option2, option3, option4, correctAnswer, audioQue);


        //System.out.println("Can you identify this sound?");
        File noise = new File(String.valueOf(audioQue));
        PlaySound(noise);
        //System.out.println(option1 + option2 + option3 + option4);

        if(correctAnswer.getModel().isPressed())
        {
            label.setText("Correct!");
        }




    }
}
```

and here is my second one with the GUI

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    private int clicks = 0;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Can you identify this sound?");
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private Object ActionEvent;


    public GUI(String optionA, String optionB, String optionC, String optionD, JButton correct, File noise) {

        // the clickable button
        JButton buttonA = new JButton("A " + optionA);
        JButton buttonB = new JButton("B " + optionB);
        JButton buttonC = new JButton("C " + optionC);
        JButton buttonD = new JButton("D " + optionD);



        buttonA.addActionListener(this);
        buttonB.addActionListener(this);
        buttonC.addActionListener(this);
        buttonD.addActionListener(this);

        // the panel with the button and text
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(buttonA);
        panel.add(buttonB);
        panel.add(buttonC);
        panel.add(buttonD);
        panel.add(label);

        // set up the frame and display it
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    // process the button clicks
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




    }

    // create one Frame
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

Comment: You never declare `buttonA` in your main method

Comment: I tried to declare buttonA in my main method before, but then I wasn't getting the intended result.

Comment: Show your attempt at declaring `buttonA` as well as the result that it gives you. As it stands, the problem with your code is that `buttonA` doesn't exist, so step 1 is to fix that

Comment: My declaration of buttonA is in my second class with the GUI, the result im going for is for the if statement in my generateQuestion method to change the label in the GUI that shows up to correct. When I declare it in the main method it does not work, I'm not sure where the problem is, in the if statement or with the buttonA declaration.  Thank you so much for your willingness to help, I'm sorry if this is a silly question I just started learning Java this year.

Comment: In that case, remove any mentions of `buttonA` outside of the GUI class. Rather than checking for the button being clicked in your `generateQuestion()` method, handle it in your GUI class.

Comment: Personally I would recommend using an `ActionListener` to check for the button being pressed, rather than using the if statement like you are now. Here's an example https://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener/